# how to find identical strings across a data

Tags: r, string

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(df1 = structure(1:7, .Label = c("A0A023J5X5", 
"A0A023J5X7", "A0A023J5Y1", "A0A023J5Y8", "A0A023J5Z0", "A0A023J601", 
"A0A023J609"), class = "factor"), df2 = structure(1:7, .Label = c("A0A023J5X5", 
"A0A023J5X7", "A0A023J5Y1", "A0A023J5Y8", "A0A023J5Z0", "A0A023J601", 
"A0A023J609"), class = "factor"), df3 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "A0A023J5X5", "A0A023J5X7", "A0A023J5Y1"
), class = "factor"), df4 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 
7L), .Label = c("A0A023J5Y8", "D3Z2H7", "O35945", "Q6ZPS9", "Q7TMW3", 
"Q925B0-1", "Q9EPC1"), class = "factor"), df5 = structure(c(5L, 
4L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "A0A023J601", "A0A023J609", 
"O35945", "Q6ZPS9", "Q7TMW3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("df1", 
"df2", "df3", "df4", "df5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

I want to find what is the number of identical strings across each column

so an output like this is what I am looking for

```
    df1 df2 df3 df4 df5
df1 7   7   3   1   2
df2 7   7   3   1   2
df3 3   3   3   0   0
df4 1   1   0   7   3
df5 2   2   0   3   5
```

for example, column 1, has 7 strings and are identical to df2 column so it will get 7

Comment: could you explain what you mean with similar?

Comment: @Scipione Sarlo similar means exactly the same . for example `A0A023J5X5`is exactly the same as `A0A023J5X5` in the first column and second column, respectively

Comment: So, I think you sholud consider to review your question, because similar means almost equal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric), while you meant identical...whether I'm checking for similarity between two strings I may use distance function (like Levenshtein and so on), instead according to your explanation I may simply use logical operators.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that uses for loops so is likely to be slow for large data. It has to cope with "" in the original data.

```
dimension = ncol(df)
result = matrix(data=0, nrow = dimension, ncol = dimension)
for (row in 1:dimension) {
  for (col in 1:dimension) {
    intersection = intersect(df[,row], df[,col])
    # work round the "" in the data
    intersection = intersection[!intersection == ""]
    result[row,col] = length(intersection)
  }
}
result.df = data.frame(result)
names(result.df) = names(df)
row.names(result.df) = names(df)
result.df

#    df1 df2 df3 df4 df5
#df1   7   7   3   1   2
#df2   7   7   3   1   2
#df3   3   3   3   0   0
#df4   1   1   0   7   3
#df5   2   2   0   3   5
```

Comment: I liked your answer because it is loop, it is not that of use but I really appreciate your help , thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yet another solution without loops and using an outer product comparison to compare each element of the matrix to all the other elements

1) It seems that you consider empty strings as NA

```
df[df == ""] <- NA
```

2) Compare each element of the matrix to all other elements with the `outer` function. I do this one column at a time thanks to `lapply`

```
tmp <- lapply(df,  function(x) outer(x, t(df), FUN = "=="))
```

3) Sum to obtain the number of matches for each vector

```
tmp <- lapply(tmp, function(x) apply(x, 2, sum, na.rm = T))
```

4) Paste each vector in a matrix

```
do.call(rbind, tmp)

   ##     df1 df2 df3 df4 df5
   ## df1   7   7   3   1   2
   ## df2   7   7   3   1   2
   ## df3   3   3   3   0   0
   ## df4   1   1   0   7   3
   ## df5   2   2   0   3   5
```

Comment: is there a possibility to add as a separate output which files are not similar ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Note also that this reply will provide another output than the solution proposed by  @awchisholm if you have several times the same value in a column. However it is unclear from your question what would be the expected output in such a case.

Comment: I want somehow to know which string from the first column is similar to 2 and 3 and which one not

Answer (score 0):

Always begin by conceptualizing your problem. There are two distinct steps here:

1. Generate all possible combinations of unique pairs between columns
2. Find the number of unique matches (or apply whatever special comparison algorithm you choose)

#### Combinations

Take yourself back to the high school days of combinations and permutations. We'd like to develop all **combinations** of column pairs, where order does not matter. Luckily, there is a function `combn` which does just that. Let's be clean and use `df`.

```
> combn(dim(df)[2], 2)
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3     4
[2,]    2    3    4    5    3    4    5    4    5     5
> combn(names(df), 2)
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]  [,10]
[1,] "df1" "df1" "df1" "df1" "df2" "df2" "df2" "df3" "df3" "df4"
[2,] "df2" "df3" "df4" "df5" "df3" "df4" "df5" "df4" "df5" "df5"
```

Use the transpose function `t` to generate a data frame. I'm keeping this light for your example except its trivial to use the exact column names.

```
df1 <- data.frame(t(combn(5,2)))
names(df1) <- c("first", "second")
```

#### Matching Function

Based on your example, I find the simple `%in%` operator to be sufficient for your solution. Look at this example:

```
> sum(df$df1 %in% df$df5)
[1] 2
```

I use the `sapply` function to generate a simple vector of all matches. I take the `df1` data frame and use the first and second columns as column indices to our original data frame `df`, and then do a column-wise comparison.

```
df1$match <- sapply(1:dim(df1)[1], function(x) {

 sum(df[,df1[x,1]] %in% df[,df1[x,2]])

})
```

And look at the output to confirm it is correct:

```
> df1
   first second match
1      1      2     7
2      1      3     3
3      1      4     1
4      1      5     2
5      2      3     3
6      2      4     1
7      2      5     2
8      3      4     0
9      3      5     4
10     4      5     3
```

That sounded fancy, but it was, in fact, straightforward once you broke down the problem into two steps. Try to do this in the future and you will be on your way toward good programming practices.

Comment: thanks for your response but actually I don't understand your output. can you please explain it ? I cannot interpret it :-D

Comment: Sure -- add a "df" to the beginning of the numbers in the first and second column. In row 1, we see df1 maps onto df2 a total of seven times. Thus, there are 7 matches between df1 and df2. Likewise, in row 2, df1 and df3 have 3 items in common. If you go back to your original matrix post, you will notice the numbers are the same for the `match` column, only the format has changed. This is the preferred data frame format.

Comment: you have spent so much time on this I really want to thank you. I only need one more thing if you can help me, I want to know which ones are dissimilar or similar across all columns ? is there a possibility to do it?

Comment: Interesting but the values of your "match" column are not correct. For example, the number of identical values between df3 and df5 should be 0 instead of 4 according to the desired output provided by @nik. This is due probably to the empty characters.

Comment: @Gilles good eye, I will not replace the answer because it is hopefully trivial to modify values to NA and your answer has already been upvoted twice. @nik you can do this with the `!` symbol to negate your answers. Essentially, look for what is NOT in the other column and count the number of times this occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Load your data and transform your columns (df1:df5) into a unique column, then transform it into a factor to get numeric values instead of strings:

```
library(dplyr)
mydf_chr <- mydf %>% 
    mutate_all(.funs=as.character()) %>%
    mutate_all(.funs=funs(gsub(pattern="^$",replacement="NA",x=.))) %>% 
    gather(Your_string) %>% 
    mutate(value=as.factor(value))
```

Then, you may recreate your data frame using numeric levels of unique factor to identify which element in df1:df5 columns are identical (not similar...)

```
Strings <- mydf_chr$value
Numeric_strings <- as.numeric(Strings)
YourDf <- as.data.frame(matrix(Numeric_strings,nrow=7,ncol=5))
names(YourDf) <- c(paste0("df",1:5))
```

You'll get the following result:

```
  df1 df2 df3 df4 df5
1   1   1   1  11  11
2   2   2   2  10  10
3   3   3   3  12  12
4   4   4   9   4   6
5   5   5   9   8   7
6   6   6   9  13   9
7   7   7   9  14   9
```

That means, for istance, that row 4 has 3 identical strings like in your data frame:

```
  df1        df2        df3        df4        df5
4 A0A023J5Y8 A0A023J5Y8            A0A023J5Y8 A0A023J601
```

Comment: I like you answer, is it possible to make a unique list and then show which data they have in ? for example `A0A023J5X5` df1,df2,df3

Comment: You may use any function to aggregate and summarise numerical codes in your data frame, then you may check the correspondance between the numerical codes of factor levels in your data frame with this table which gives you that codes: 
`Encoding_table <- as.data.frame(c(levels(Strings))) %>% 
    mutate(Code_Number=row_number())`